# run something async in Grails 2.3

Tags: grails, asynchronous

In My Grails service, there is a part of a method I wish to run asynchronously.

Following, the doc for 2.3.x  http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0.M1/guide/async.html

I do

```
public class MyService {
    public void myMethod() {
        Promise p = task {
            // Long running task
        }
        p.onError { Throwable err ->
            println "An error occured ${err.message}"
        }
        p.onComplete { result ->
            println "Promise returned $result"
        }
        // block until result is called
        def result = p.get()
    }
}
```

However, I want to execute mine without any blocking.  The `p.get()` method blocks.  How do I execute the promise without any sort of blocking.  I don't care if `myMethod()` returns, it is a kinda of fire and forget method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, according to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html#promises) if you don't call `.get()` or `.waitAll()` but rather just make use of `onComplete` you can run your task without blocking the current thread.

Here is a very silly example that I worked up in the console to as a proof of concept.

```
import static grails.async.Promises.*
def p = task {
    // Long running task
    println 'Off to do something now ...'
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println '... that took 5 seconds'
    return 'the result'
}

p.onError { Throwable err ->
    println "An error occured ${err.message}"
}
p.onComplete { result ->
    println "Promise returned $result"
}

println 'Just to show some output, and prove the task is running in the background.'
```

Running the above example gives you the following output:

```
Off to do something now ...  
Just to show some output, and prove the task is running in the background.  
... that took 5 seconds   
Promise returned the result
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  When I define onError, I always get the following exception. org.grails.async.factory.gpars.LoggingPoolFactory ERROR Async execution error: null

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.grails.async.factory.gpars.GparsPromise$_onError_closure2.doCall(GparsPromise.groovy:72)
 at groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataCallback$1.run(DataCallback.java:62)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: @wheels53 have you found solution for this NPE?. i'm also getting same when i define onError